# Can you advise on the construction of a large segmented primary mirror (hobbiest)?

Tags: telescope, telescope-lens, mirror-making

I am interested in experimenting with the building of a large parabolic primary mirror constructed from 4" hexagon mirrors mounted on a "rough" parabolic surface with either 3 screw adjustments for each individual mirror or (eventually) Arduino controlled adjusters.  Any constructive advise on methods or procedure would be most helpful.

Comment: That sounds very hard.  How much experience have you had in mirror making?  I don't think this is an obvious first project.

Comment: I you would like to make a solar concentrator for boiling water, this can be done with screws. But if you want to make even a very low power telescope you'll need a computer program and detailed image analysis to know how your Arduino-controlled adjusters should tilt each segment. If you have two rings of hexagons that's 18 mirrors x 3 degrees of freedom per mirror (height, and x and y tilts), or 54 independent degrees of freedom. All you have is a blurry image and what's needed is a computer program that can analyze the image and dither all the axes to figure out how to converge on

Comment: While the process of hand-grinding and figuring a one-piece mirror for amateurs is quite well understood and documented, I thing figuring a segment of a paraboloid without a sophisticated computer-controlled grinding machine would be impossible, and I don't think it is possible to divide an already-figured mirror into segments without destroying its figure.

Comment: Did anyone do the calculation or simulation on the goodness of imaging, if that were done with flat 1st-surface mirrors (which are much more readily available)?